# I can't get navbar to collapse in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar won't collapse and I've been trying to figure out why for hours. Watched a few tutorials and still can't get it to work. I'm new to bootstrap and would appreciate help!

```
   <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Template by Mixon</a>

                    <button class="navbar-toggle" data="collapse" data-target="collapse">
                        lol
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

       </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">` is inside the `navbar-header`, it's not good, it should be after.

---

After change

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" data="collapse" data-target="collapse">
                    lol
                </button>
```

By

```
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myid">
                    lol
                </button>
```

---

Here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ez0VghLMGr)

Extract :

```
   <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Template by Mixon</a>

                    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myid">
                        lol
                    </button>
                </div>


                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myid">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
       </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the button markup to..

`<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse">`

http://bootply.com/pMPGhwKx3u